# First photos under pasted url on facebook wall

Tags: facebook

When I wanna add a link on facebook wall, Facebook make search for photos under pasted link. But it gets only first 6 photos.

I'm curiouss if there is some class, id or rel atributte important for facebook which will indicate exactly what image we want to show?

Comment: Ok. I think that I have just found an answer. If some one are intressted: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `og:image` meta property to assign images to be used on liked and shared items on Facebook, like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
```

It's described as:

> og:image - An image URL which should
>   represent your object within the
>   graph. The image must be at least 50px
>   by 50px and have a maximum aspect
>   ratio of 3:1. We support PNG, JPEG and
>   GIF formats. You may include multiple
>   og:image tags to associate multiple
>   images with your page.

For more information have a look at the documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/). You can use the [Facebook URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) to inspect where it is fetching the different meta data, such as the images.